# Transfer data from one worksheet to another in excel

Tags: vba, excel

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Rpgd.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UX0uQ.png)

Hi, I want to transfer the data from the "Order form" into the "Contact sheet". As can be shown from the images, when I type in the details of title, first name, last name, etc. I want it to appear exactly the same thing in the "Contact sheet" given. I have tried some copy and paste macro, but it does not seem to work in my case. Can you please help me with vba or macro??
Thank you very much!!

Comment: Show some code of yours

Comment: Hi @OanhHoang. You will find that the amount of help you get from us is directly proportional to the amount of effort it seems you have put in to finding the solution *yourself*. Questions like this one and your other question show lack of effort and will be downvoted for that reason. I'm telling you this now as a warning because if you continue to receive downvotes you will be restricted from posting new questions -- and then we definitely won't be able to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that can help you ! 
Maybe to use this code create a button on your sheet and when you click on this button you execute this code below. That's a way to do, and they are many other ways to do it !

```
Sheets("Order form").Range("X1").Value = Sheets("Contact sheet").Range("X1").Value
```

Good coding !